# Is there available REGA or COMET versions for downloading & using on a local machine?

Tags: python, hiv

I am currently working on verifying the subgenotyping of our sequences and a subsample from the **Los Alamos NL** database. My supervisor has recommended using **REGA** & **COMET** for this purpose. While our dataset, which consists of slightly > 1,000 sequences, can be easily subgenotyped using the online versions of these tools, the **LANL** dataset is significantly larger, prompting me to consider local installations. Unfortunately, however, I have been unable to find the source repositories for **REGA** & **COMET**.
I did come across a link to the entire [**REGA DB**](https://rega.kuleuven.be/cev/regadb/download) but I am unsure if it contains the subgenotyping tool or if the last can be installed separately. I am also interested in exploring other locally installable tools of comparable quality.
In my search, I found [**jpHMM**](http://jphmm.gobics.de/jphmm.html), which is available for download and free use. However, it seems to be less frequently used in publications compared to the aforementioned ones.

I would appreciate any insights on the quality of **jpHMM** or any other recommended tools for local installation (even as packages, e.g. for *Python*).

If you have experience with these subgenotyping tools or any relevant advice, please share your thoughts! Your help is greatly appreciated!

Best regards,